# Symfony2 Proxy Fails Generation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, proxy

I have a problem in Symfony2 where a single entity (out of many) appears not to have a proxy. its always this entity and none other. It generates this error:

```
Jan 18 14:11:39 shiftmarketprd app/web.3: [18-Jan-2015 03:11:38 UTC] PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/app/app/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__ShiftMarketApiBundleEntityUserUserPreferences.php' (include_path='.:/app/.heroku/php/lib/php') in /app/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php on line 207
```

Various solutions suggest that the cache hasn't been warmed up, and hence the entity doesnt exist - however, (i) I know that the cache has been warmed up and (ii) this is the ONLY entity that causes this error. Its also been suggested that the issue is when an entity has an incorrect type hint (using int) but I don't have that either. The only thing I do think is unusual about the enitity is that it uses bools - could that be it?

```
/**
 * @var bool
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
 * @Expose
 * @Groups({"get","current"})
 * @AccessType("public_method")
 */
protected $notifyemail;
```

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: sudo chmod -R 777 app/cache

Comment: Does that class maybe extend the wrong base or something? Can you paste the code for an entity that works and for the one that does not?

Comment: @dzuelke - it doesnt extend a base class (though most of the others do). Thats rather a large amount of code...

Comment: @John Smith - all the other cache files are successfully created, so its not a permissions issue.